# PAK archives and zlib (zlib.dylib)

Tags: iphone, zip, archive, zlib, libz

I'm currently writing an iPhone app where I need to uncompress several files from .pak archive.  I'm assuming libz.dylib will probably have the ability to do this but I'm having a hard time find any code on the subject.
Anyone got any example code or can point me in the right direction?  Any help at all would be much appreciated.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "PAK"?

If it's actually a .zip, look up minizip or [ziparchive](http://code.google.com/p/ziparchive/), which may do what you want.

Comment: Basically .pak (later .pk2/.pk3) is an old school format for archiving game media into a single file.  It was used in most ID Software games such as Doom, Quake.  It's a very simple format but I was hoping someone already had some code rather than me having to write something from scratch. http://www.gamedev.net/reference/programming/features/pak/

Comment: Yeah, those are actually just .zip archives. See ZipArchive.